# .Net Framework Data Provider not found

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I got a project to complete some tasks on it, but when I try debug I have this error in

```
DbProviderFactory Dbfactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(MasterConnectionProvider);
```

With my MasterConnectionProvider is System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity

*Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.*

I check the version of sql compact installé is the same with dll 3.5.1.0

Any help please

Comment: I wonder if you should first reinstall the .net 3.5 SP1

Comment: in the project they using framework 4 are this affect on it !!

Comment: Sure but the CE.Entity provider you have is a CLR 2 (.net 3.5 SP1) version, can you install the 4.0 SQL Compact?

Comment: @Preet Sangha :I have install the 4.0 SQL Compact but the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DB Factory Provider name you want is:

```
"System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
```

You have - "System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity"

i.e.

```
DbProviderFactory Dbfactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5")
```

PK  ;)

Comment: it work but how give me this project tell me that it work fine !!! then why I have to change this ?

Comment: sorry Akrem - I can't answer that question!!